# In R, combine the same summary column of different dataframes into one new dataframe

Tags: r

I have about 40 dataframes (df1,df2,df3,etc) with the same structure with 25 columns each.
I can run the summary(df1), summary(df2), etc..
The summary includes several columns, I am interested in this column of the summary:

for df1, it is

```
stage 
stage1  :2222 
stage2  :1212 
stage3  :8898
```

for df2, it is

```
stage 
stage1  :2334 
stage2  :9887 
stage3  :2344
```

for df3, it is

```
stage 
stage1  :5334 
stage2  :4887 
stage3  :344
```

etc

I want to create a new df with :

```
           df1      df2      df3      ...
stage1     2222     2334     5334     ... 
stage2     1212     9887     4887     ...
stage3     8898     2344     344      ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is a simple `cbind(df1, df2, df3, ...)` not an option?

Comment: what are these numbers? `mean` ?

Comment: no. Those numbers are not in the dataframes, only in the summaries.
Those numbers mean that for example in df1, there are 2222 rows with stage1, 1212 rows with stage2, and 8898 rows with stage3.

Comment: What @RafaelC means is that `summary()` gives a series of numbers, from `Min.` to `Max.` what are the numbers you posted in your question? What is `stage1`, `stage2` etc?

Comment: No, summary() does not always return min max mean etc. In the rows there are sales opportunities, that are either in stage1, stage2 or stage3.
Summary() here shows how many stage1 opportunities there are, how many stage2 opportunities there are and how many stage3 opportunities there are

Comment: could you provide a sample for us to work with? That would help us finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like column `stage` in your dataframes is a factor with 3 levels: `stage1`, `stage2`, `stage3`. I cannot know for certain since you haven't provided a reproducible example, but if this is the case:

Say you have dataframes

```
df <- data.frame(stage = as.factor(c('stage1', 'stage2', 'stage1', 'stage3', 'stage2', 'stage2')))
df2 <- data.frame(stage = as.factor(c('stage3', 'stage2', 'stage3', 'stage3', 'stage2', 'stage1')))
```

You can ask the amount of occurences by using `summary()`

```
summary(df$stage)
#stage1 stage2 stage3 
#     2      3      1
```

Combining the results by using `rbind()` and you get your occurrences of stage in one dataframe.

```
dfstages <- as.data.frame(rbind(summary(df$stage), summary(df2$stage)))
#  stage1 stage2 stage3
#1      2      3      1
#2      1      2      3
```

Comment: Thanks, it should work.
I am still wondering if there is a way to combine the summaries of different dataframes into a new dataframe by using the summary() only.

Comment: I edited my answer, apparently `summary` and `table` with a factor share the same results

Answer (score 0):

By adding the data frame names to each frame and using `table()` one can avoid having to process all of the variables in the data frame via `summary()` just to obtain frequency counts for one column. 
Here is a another approach using `table()` that includes the data frame names

After generating the sample data we assign the data frames to a list to add a column for the data frame names, and then count the frequencies with `table()`. By including the data frame name as the second dimension in the table, we obtain the desired output: rows with the values of the `stage` variable, columns with data frame names.

```
# 
# create example data

df1 <-data.frame(stage =c(rep("stage1",2222),
                         rep("stage2",1212),
                         rep("stage3",8898)))

df2 <-data.frame(stage =c(rep("stage1",2334),
                          rep("stage2",9887),
                          rep("stage3",2344)))


df3 <-data.frame(stage =c(rep("stage1",5334),
                          rep("stage2",4887),
                          rep("stage3",344)))

theList <- list(df1=df1,df2=df2,df3=df3)

# add data frame name as column in each data frame

for(i in 1:length(theList)) {
     theList[[i]]$dfname <- names(theList[i])
}

# rbind to one data frame before generating frequencies 
theData <- do.call(rbind,theList)

table(theData$stage , theData$dfname)
```

...and the output:

```
> table(theData$stage , theData$dfname)

          df1  df2  df3
  stage1 2222 2334 5334
  stage2 1212 9887 4887
  stage3 8898 2344  344
>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. I still wonder, though, if there is an easy way to combine the columns from the summaries, because summary() does the "summary" itself without having to code anything, maybe the easiest is to create a summary dataframe for every dataframe and then combine them together.

Comment: @Tilsight -  `summary()` by itself does not include a way to tag the data with the data frame from which the summary was taken, and apears to be an important part of your request. Also, if you provide more detail in your question, the community can provide better guidance. See [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details.